# using htaccess/htpasswd to protect an individual Wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a premium content Wordpress page I am trying to 'protect'. I have a 3rd party .htaccess/.htpasswd system I am currently using on a non-cms html site to protect similar content. Is there a way to make an individual Wordpress page protected with a third party .htaccess/.htpasswd system?

I've searched for, but cannot find, a memberhip plugin that would use a third party member system instead of its own. I also cannot use the page protect feature in admin as again I need to use the .htaccess/.htpasswd system.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not working.

```
AuthUserFile    /home/mysite/public_html/ccprocess/.htpass
AuthName        "Member Area"
AuthType Basic
<Files "testblog.mysite.com/test-paid-gallery">
require valid-user
</Files>
```

I type in testblog.mysite.com/test-paid-gallery and the wordpress page comes up without asking for user / password. In researching some stuff it appears the

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working. AuthUserFile /home/mysite/public_html/ccprocess/.htpass AuthName "Member Area" AuthType Basic <Files "testblog.mysite.com/test-paid-gallery"> require valid-user </Files> I type in testblog.mysite.com/test-paid-gallery and the wordpress page comes up without asking for user / password. In researching some stuff it appears the <Files may not work because wordpress pages aren't files, but info in a database.

Answer (score -1):

To protect one page you add the following to .htaccess (or htaccess.txt)

```
AuthUserFile /path/to/htpasswd/file/.htpasswd
AuthName "Name of Page"
AuthType Basic
<Files "mypage.html">
 require valid-user
</Files>
```

Just update the path to your .htpasswd file and name of page.

---

### **Edit 7/31/2013**

At the time this worked on environments that I was working with. Depending on server setup the actual script can vary. As attached urls show there are two similar but different scripts for different hosting companies. If you require a specific script, please check your hosting FAQ/Support section

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/htaccess/password-single-file-htaccess

http://support.hostgator.com/articles/cpanel/how-to-password-protect-one-file

Comment: Thanks James! To be sure, i add this updated .htaccess file to the root of my blog folder?

Comment: Yes. And make sure you put the url in the <FILES> Section EX: URL = example.com/10/12/2011/Content - Files = "10/12/2011/Content".